# Sources on Madhvacharya's Beliefs of Eternal Damnation and Pancha Bhedas

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, dvaita, madhvacharya

I like to know what scriptural verses Shri Madhvacharya used to point out that eternal damnation exists.

I also like to know whether Shri Madhvacharya believed that each object is different from another object. Did he, **not** his disciples, specifically say that each "vastu" is different from another "vastu," or each "maha bhuta" is different from another "maha bhuta?" Or did he only say each "jada" is different from another "jada," as per his citation of the Paramopanishad that mentioned the five bhedas? To me "jada" is a vague word and only seems to refer to substances that are insentient from the perspective of absolute reality and not from the perspective of everyday experience. Quotations from Shri Madhvacharya's writings will help.

PS: I can only read English and Bengali and only have English copies of Shri Madhvacharya's Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya, Anu Bhasya, and Brahma Sutra Bhasya. Therefore, I have a limited understanding of his tenets.

Comment: eternal punishment for a finite crime is not possible. it can however be used as a scare tactic for rowdy elements (aka Abrahamic religion followers) who would otherwise never repent. However, samsara itself is an eternal damnation in the sense that one can cyclically keep doing punya and paap and keep revolving in it forever.

Comment: @ram Did Shri Madhvacharya specify eternal damnation (or tamo yoga) to mean returning to samsara forever and continuing to do and spread sin?

Comment: i wrote up an answer to similar question earlier - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34681/4435

Comment: @ram Thank you for the link